# .net assembly's StrongName and PublicKeyToken in its display name format

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, strongname, publickeytoken

I checked the info regarding the format of the display name of an AssemblyName in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) source, it says:

> The format of the display name of an AssemblyName is a comma-delimited Unicode string that begins with the name, as follows:
>
> *Name <,Culture = CultureInfo> <,Version = Major.Minor.Build.Revision> <, StrongName> <,PublicKeyToken> '\0'*
>
> Name is the textual name of the assembly. CultureInfo is the RFC1766-format-defined culture. Major, Minor, Build, and Revision are the major version, minor version, build number, and revision number of the assembly. **StrongName** is *the hexadecimal-encoded low-order 64 bits of the hash value of the public key* generated using the SHA-1 hashing algorithm and the public key specified by SetPublicKey. PublicKeyToken is the hexadecimal-encoded public key specified by **SetPublicKey**.

Then checked [SetPublicKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.setpublickeytoken.aspx), it says:

> Sets the public key token, which is the *last 8 bytes of the SHA-1 hash of the public key* under which the application or assembly is signed.

So it sounds that StrongName is the same as PublicKeyToken in the above display format specification, then why are the both got listed in the same format side by side? When I tried to print out an assembly's AssemblyName by using **AssemblyName.FullName**, it only showed something like:

> System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

So no StrongName shows up, and doesn't follow the order specified above, ie, the version info came before the culture info.

Can anyone give some explain? Thanks.

Comment: The field order is not fixed, see later on the msdn page you linked: _Also note that except for Name, which must come first, the lexical order of parameters is unimportant_. As for the `StrongName`, the system doesn't seem to be producing that as output, and silently ignores it if I pass it as input.

Comment: It is StrongName **or** PublicKeyToken.  Key phrase is "If the full public key is known, then PublicKey may be substituted for StrongName".  I've never seen anybody do this, no idea what the point might be.

Comment: Thanks you two. My main confusion here is the **relationship** between _StrongName_ and _PublicKeyToken_.